# Finding values from a list that are higher and lower than a certain value

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
x = [5, 8, 12] 
y = 9
lower = [_ for _ in x if _ < y][-1]
higher = [_ for _ in x if _ > y][0]
print lower, higher
```

This finds a value that is lower, and a value that is higher than a given input (y) in the list x. x is sorted.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: do you need the results as materialized lists, or are views sufficient?

Comment: Just the individual values from the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `x` is sorted:

```
>>> bisect.bisect(x, y)
2
>>> x[:bisect.bisect(x, y)]
[5, 8]
>>> x[bisect.bisect(x, y):]
[12]
```

Comment: Perhaps use a variable to store the bisection point in, to make it a tiny bit more efficient? +1 anyway.

Comment: Absolutely. That's just PoC up there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use filter.

```
x = [5, 8, 12] 
y = 9
lower = filter(lambda n:n<y, x)
higher = filter(lambda n:n>y, x)
print lower, higher
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it's sorted, you can use `groupby from itertools`:

```
>>> x = [5, 8, 12]
>>> y = 9
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(group[1]) for group in groupby(x, lambda c: c < y)]
[[5, 8], [12]]
```

`groupby` returns a list of tuple with the form of : `(key_function_return_value, list-like iterable object)`. Thats why `list(group[1])` is needed to convert the list-like object explicitly to a list.